# Angular template variable reference

Tags: javascript, angular, web

Here is a weird problem in Angular:

```
<input #pin1 type="password">
<p>You entered: {{pin1.value}}</p>
```

If you type something in `<input>`, the `<p>`'s content will not change which means `pin1.value` does not have value, does it mean the variable reference `#pin1` does not work?

On the other hand, if we add a function to pass the reference, it will work.

```
<input #pin2 type="password" (input)="test(pin2)">
<p>You entered: {{pin2.value}}</p>
```

where `test=function(x){console.log(x);}`

For this `<input>`, if we type something, the the `<p>`'s content will change to corresponding text which implies `#pin2` works.

So, the question is, in Angular, why we must use function to pass variable reference firstly then we can use it, why we cannot directly use variable reference.

Comment: actually, the added function "test"  can be any function, only requirement is we pass variable reference into function.So I do not understand why we must do it? Why can't we just declare a variable reference, and then directly use it in template expression or interpolation.

Comment: After several test, I found we even do not need pass variable reference into function, for example: <input #pin2 type="password" (input)="test()"> where test = function(){}, and it still works. However, if we delete the event binding, just <input #pin2 type="password">, the variable reference will not work. This problem becomes more weird, can anyone explain it??

Comment: The reason is simple: events handled from output event bindings trigger change detection.

Comment: thank you for reply, but what's the relationship with template variable reference, why we must trigger event first?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable

Comment: @YuiMoe: With `(input)="test(pin2)"` you're using a kind of one way binding and this will not work. Pls. check Mehdis answer... it's the correct two way binding and will work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that is not how binding works.
What you did is creating a reference to input Dom object. At the time of the creation, the value of that Dom element (input) was empty. hence no value showing in your `<p>` tag.
if you want to see the value as you type then you are looking for a 2 way binding like so

```
<input [(ngModel)]="pin" type="password">
<p>You entered: {{pin}}</p>
```

Assuming that pin is declared in your ts file.

As to why the value was updating when you introduces a function, the answer is because Angular will be calling that function test(pin2) whenever you type something into that input which results in running a detect change on the model.

Long story short, Angular is a Model driven framework, if you need a value, you shouldn't need to get the DOM element to get the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

I may get an ambiguous answer, it may be related to event binding, which means "view-to-source", if we didn't bind any event, the view (user interaction) cannot pass data to source (the component class), so variable reference may not work, but there are still some question like the template references should not be related to source side, since such variables aren't member/properties of component class.

Answer (score 0):

it is so werired behaviour in angular 
this code not working

```
<input #inputval type="text"  />
<app-newcomp [testValue]="inputva.value"></app-newcomp>
```

but if you add "input" event to the input element then it will work

```
<input #inputval type="text" (input)="someFunctionInTs($event)"  />
<app-newcomp [testValue]="inputva.value"></app-newcomp>
```